# How to override some default CurrentCulture values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cultureinfo

I need to override the default DayNames of the current (or specified) CurrentCulture object.

I have tried to accomplish this in several ways:

1) At the Global.asax level:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(XXX);
    string[] newNames = { YYY };
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames = newNames;
}
```

2) At the Controller level:

```
public HomeController() {
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(XXX);
    string[] newNames = { YYY };
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames = newNames;
}
```

The specified "CurrentCulture" object is applied correctly (according to the specified XXX culture name). I can see a culture-specific day name via the `@DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd")` expression.
However, the specified "DayNames" object seems to be ignored (however, I can see that both the "CurrentCulture" and "DayNames" properties are applied correctly in the debugger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to override the default AbbreviatedDayNames instead:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(...);
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames = ...;
}

@DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd")
```